# How does the sorcerer's Careful Spell Metamagic option work with the Thunderwave spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, saving-throw, metamagic

The *Player Handbook's* entry on the sorcerer's Careful Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option states that:

> When you cast a spell that ***forces other creatures to make a saving throw***, you can protect some of those creatures from the spell’s ***full force***. To do so, you spend 1 sorcery point and choose a number o f those creatures up to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one creature). A chosen creature ***automatically succeeds on its saving throw against the spell***.

However, the description of [*thunderwave*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thunderwave) states:

> Each creature in a 15-foot cube originating from you ***must make*** a Constitution ***saving throw***. On a failed save, a creature takes 2d8 thunder damage and is pushed 10 feet away from you. On a ***successful save***, the creature takes ***half as much damage*** and isn’t pushed.

Would the creatures protected by Careful Spell still take half damage from the sorcerer's *thunderwave* spell? It seems to contradict the statement that "you can protect some of those creatures from the spell’s full force".

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, they will still take half damage.

This doesn't contradict the text at all, because you have successfully protected them from the **full** force of the spell.  You aren't able to protect them completely, but they haven't taken the full damage the spell would have otherwise inflicted.

Comment: Additionally, they're guaranteed to not be forcibly moved.

Comment: Thanks Louis for clearing that up. Guess I'm not taking that Metamagic till I'm level 17.

Comment: @EmilT.M.: Actually, this is arguably one of the **best metamagic** for team play. Do not judge it with only one spell in mind; on many spells, a successful save means that nothing happens. Furthermore, even if your teammates still take half-damage, it can nonetheless be a good option: drop of Fireball that does 40 points of damage? Your Bear Barbarian teammate will take a measly 10 points of damage on their huge HP pool, while all foes around them are incinerated on the spot (providing they fail their save) => without Careful Spell, this may not be a tactical option.

Comment: And keep in mind any rogues/monks with evasion will not take any damage on a successful Dex save, and you can force that success to happen.